# Organizing JSON files while appending through Python (discord.py) input

Tags: python, json, discord.py, append

I'm currently making a bot on Discord.py right now, and one of the commands takes input that would be stored into a JSON file. One of the keys is a sort of ID associated for each object, and its format is basically a sort of alphanumeric code. A sample version of the JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "tbg210915-1",
      "date": "September 15, 2021",
      "time": "21:09",
      "url": "https://example.com"
    },
    {
      "id": "tbg210915-2",
      "date": "September 15, 2021",
      "time": "21:09",
      "url": "https://example2.com"
    },
    {
      "id": "tbg210917-1",
      "date": "September 17, 2021",
      "time": "01:33",
      "url": "https://example3.com"
    },
  ]
}
```

What I want to happen is that if I input a new object dict whose id is `tbg210916-1`, it would be appended between `tbg210915-2` and `tbg210917-1`.

Here is how the command works right now so you know how these are currently being appended:

```
# function to generate the aforementioned id
def generateImgID(file, type, img_date):
  # turning input data type into abbreviated codes
  convert_list = {...} # a list of types one can input and what their corresponding code would be
    
  if type in convert_list.keys():
    m = convert_list[type]

  # converting Month dd, yyyy format to yymmdd 
  d = datetime.datetime.strptime(img_date, '%B %d, %Y').strftime('%y%m%d')

  # that number at the end thingy signifying what nth pic that is in a given day
  new = open(file)
  data = json.load(new)

  result = Counter(data.values())[img_date]
  if result == 0:
    num = 1
  else:
    num = result + 1
  
  n = str(num)

  return f'{m}{d}-{n}'

# command to add new pic to database of json files
@client.command()
async def addpic(ctx):
  def check(message):
    return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel

  ... # here is basically a multi-step input process then for the bot to ask the user what to input

# adding all input to json
  with open(f'image json/{type}.json', 'r') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)

    data[f'{type}'].append({
      "id": img_id,
      "date": img_date,
      "time": img_time,
      "url": img_url
    })
  
  with open(f'image json/{type}.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp, indent = 2)

  await ctx.send(embed = successembed)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try sorting the list every time you append a new element i.e:

```py
data.append(newelement)
data.sort(key=lambda x: x['id'])
```

Which will sort the list 'data' **inplace**